# How to use OpenJPA 2.2 on WebSphere 7.0?

Tags: java, websphere, openjpa

I'm starting a project where I need to use OpenJPA 2.2 and run on WAS 7.0.

How do I make WAS 7.0 pick up the OpenJPA 2.2 jar instead of using its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may configure OpenJPA 2.2 as outlined in WAS7 infocenter at [Using third-party persistence providers](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html) article.

It is stated in this article that in addition to using JPA providers from other vendors, "Applications can also specify an Apache OpenJPA provider that is other than the version that is included with the application server."