# how to override the openjpa2.2.2.jar in was7

Tags: jpa, openjpa, websphere-7

I am using the WAS7 in one of my Test Env. My Application contains the Jar of openjpa2.x.jar. While Testing and saving the application it is throwing the openjpa unique constraint exception.

After the verifying the classloading functionality of WAS7, I Observed that WAS7 always the considers the default jars, which are come from WAS Server.
I Tried the all the possible scenarios of PARENT_FIRST/PARENT_LAST of Server level and application level, but none of the them are worked out.

Can some one please help me how to resolve this issue and how to override the web-inf/lib jars with WAS7 default jars. Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use OpenJPA 2.2 on WebSphere 7.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279691/how-to-use-openjpa-2-2-on-websphere-7-0)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279691/how-to-use-openjpa-2-2-on-websphere-7-0) post. You would need to create isolated shared library, if you want to override openJPA provided in WAS.